# how to set one static <li> as a last entry in generic <ul> with many <li>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

i have generic  ( all data will be loaded in javascript/jquery function) list.

**function**:

```
var contentarticles = articles.contentarticles,
    article,
    $out = $("#articlesOutput");

    contentarticlesAll = contentarticles;

    for (var i = 0; i < contentarticles.length; i++) {
        if (!article || article.title != contentarticles[i].title) {
            article = contentarticles[i];

            document.getElementById('articleForNaviTopTitle').innerHTML = contentarticles[currentImageNr - 1].title;
            document.getElementById('articleForNaviTopStepNr').innerHTML = currentImageNr;

            var articlesOutput = [
                '<li><a href="./certifiedTraining.html?step=', i + 1, '">',
                article.title,
                '</li>'
            ].join("");
            $out.append(articlesOutput);
        }
    }
```

**it looks like:**

```
1. step 1
2. step 2
3. step 3
```

but i want to add some static link into it.
doing it like this:

```
<ul id="articlesOutput">
    <li> <a href="./certifiedTraining.html?step=fragenkatalog">Fragenkatalog</a></li>
</ul>
```

**and its my output:**

```
    1. Fragenkatalog
    2. step 1
    3. step 2
    4. step 3
```

how to make the static entry as a last, **like this**?

```
  1. step 1
  2. step 2
  3. step 3
  4. Fragenkatalog
```

Comment: Can you show the code that adds elements to the list?

Comment: here is updated question

Comment: strange person who has rated this question with -1. be brave and say why you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method. This adds content as the preceding sibling of an element.

First, store a reference to the element that you want to keep at the end.

```
$out = $("#articlesOutput"),
$last = $out.children().first();
```

Then insert the new content before that element:

```
$last.before(articlesOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jquery for it and use this code to get the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#articlesOutput").append("<li>Fragenkatalog</li>");
 });
```